Reflector 4 does not open on win 10 logs show System.Management.ManagementException: Not found
I was using reflector 4 for the trial period and once it was over I wanted to upgrade. Trying to open just leads to the message "Reflector 4 has encountered and error and must now close. A log has been created at.."
The logs says:
Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'Reflector.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. ---> System.Management.ManagementException: Not found
I already did a full installation / uninstall 2 times, and also reinstalled .net, but nothing works. I installed it at a Virtual Machine with Win10 and it works there.
What else can I try? (reflector's support is practically non existing)
